# How to allow a different company to use our web app?

Tags: api, security, web-applications, architecture

We are developing a web app that has users and payments. We need to use it ourselves and we need to allow other companies to use it as well. All instances of the app must use the same database and the same payments account. And it's preferred that each front-end is completely separate.

Here are the ways I can think of:

1) Use OAuth. This is a perfect approach but I don't think each front-end can be completely separate - in other words each app instance would link to the same password and payment forms and then redirect back to the app instance when the user is done with the form.

2) Just give the other company the whole app and let them deploy a completely separate instance. The downside is that we would need to give them our database and payment credentials.

3) Load the front-end of our app into an iframe on their site. Is this even possible? If so it seems like it would meet all my requirements but it seems a bit hacky...not sure of all the drawbacks.

Are there any other options that would allow for the same database and payments account and completely separate front-ends?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the other company to use your company domain or sub domain or their own domain.?

### Your company domain

In this case, create a separate login page. Once user is loggedin, create a custom UI for the logged in user and show the pages for user and payment. It is single UI and it can render based on the user preference like custom font, logs etc.

### Company Subdomain

This is a popular model used in Software as Service business. Based on the subdomain, create the custom page and this page will access the services with cusomter id. You can also provide a module for the customer to upload the images, select the font etc.
All the services and transaction will have customer id and easy to track.

### Customer domain

Expose the user and payment info as restful webservice and let the customer to create a webpage and use the exposed services.

Comment: Note that for the "customer domain" case you should use oAuth approach !